# R shiny Error - Trying to create R shiny Dashboard with .csv dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wsj/college-salaries

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hello I am trying to create a Rshiny dashboard, I have done the following R script, but function error doesn't let the web page load and it crashes with the following error.  Thank you I had to do R shiny for the first time for just a week as i took a wrong elective, this is the final assignment i need to complete to finish grad school, I've been trying different stuff to get it sorted but didnt reach anywhere for a week. If you have a little time on your hand and provide a little help for developing a quick dashboard with this dataset (nothing fancy just 2-3 page subitem for any type for analytical graphs, literally super basic), it would really really helpful.

Dataset:** https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wsj/college-salaries **

```
 library(shiny)
  library (shinydashboard)
  library (shinythemes)
  library (readr)
  library (ggplot2)
  library(shinyWidgets)


setwd("C:/")

degrees <- read.csv("C: /degrees-that-pay-back.csv", header =  TRUE)
college <- read.csv("C:  /salaries-by-college-type.csv", header =  TRUE)
salaries <- read.csv("C:/ /salaries-by-region.csv", header =  TRUE)

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)





ui <- fluidPage(
  setBackgroundColor(color = c("#66e0ff", "#00a3cc", "#003d4d")),
  titlePanel("Where does it pay to attend college?"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(tags$style(".well {background-color:#e6f9ff;}"),
                 sliderInput(inputId = "range",
                             label = "Chose the year range:",
                             min = 30000, max = 1000000, value = c(30000,100000)),
                 selectInput(inputId = "dis",
                             label = "Chose the School type",
                             choices = unique(college$School.Type)),
                 checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "con",
                                    label = "Region of the school ",
                                    choices = unique(salaries$Region),
                                    selected = unique(salaries$Region)[1])
                 
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1")) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  df_dat <- observeEvent({
    
   
    req(input$con, input$dis, input$range) 
    
    
    df_dat <- filter(degrees, between(degrees$Starting.Median.Salary, input$range[1], input$range[2]), college$School.Type == input$dis, salaries$Region %in% input$con)
    
    return(df_dat)
  })
  

  observe(print(str(df_dat())))
  
  # create a graph 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
    
    
    req(df_dat())
    
    # plot filtered data
    ggplot(df_dat(), aes(x = degrees$Starting.Median.Salary, y = college$School.Name)) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = salaries$Region))+      
      geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am trying to create a dashboard with R shiny just something using the following dataset, link: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wsj/college-salaries Really appericiate the help! Thank you. :)

Comment: I would recommend you check the `flexdashboard` package: https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/. This package makes it incredibly easy to create dashboards in a form that is intuitively close to `Rmarkdown` notebooks.

Comment: _... and it crashes with the following error ..._ you did not post the error (or hid it very well)

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some guesses on what you were wanting, but I think I came up with roughly what you were looking for. I wrote my notes in line to help you and show where you were missing things. For example, your `observeEvent()` wasn't observing anything, and you were trying to store it as a variable which I don't think you can do. I also think you needed the data sets combined to be able to filter, otherwise they would be of a different length making it unplottable. Hopefully this gives you an idea on how to progress:

```
library(shiny)
# library (shinydashboard) #Not needed for this
# library (shinythemes) #Don't have shinythemes, not necessary to your question
library (readr)
library (ggplot2)
# library(shinyWidgets) #Not needed for this


# setwd("C:/")  #I don't need to change wd so I blocked this


# library(shiny) #Duplicated
# library(shinyWidgets) #Duplicated
# library(ggplot2) #Duplicated
library(dplyr) #Moved file read in after dplyr to have mutate

#At least how I interpeted your use of the data, I don't know if the degrees data set is used. You just filter the starting median salary
#But there is also the starting median salary in the college dataset, and so I just filtered that column instead
# degrees <- read.csv("degrees-that-pay-back.csv", header =  TRUE)%>% #Adjusted csv location to my default directory
#   mutate(Starting.Median.Salary = parse_number(as.character(Starting.Median.Salary))) #Parse number to make currency into character then numeric
college <- read.csv("salaries-by-college-type.csv", header =  TRUE)%>% #Adjusted csv location to my default directory
  mutate(Starting.Median.Salary = parse_number(as.character(Starting.Median.Salary))) #Parse number to make currency into character then numeric
salaries <- read.csv("salaries-by-region.csv", header =  TRUE) #Adjusted csv location to my default directory 

total<-college%>% #Combined the dataset into ONE dataframe instead of three, though I'm not actually using the degrees data
  left_join(salaries%>% #Join college data with salaries data
              select(School.Name, Region), #Only need school name and region columns from the salaries data
            by = "School.Name")%>% #Join by the school.name column
  mutate(Region = ifelse(is.na(Region), "Other", as.character(Region))) #Filtering when NA wasn't working right, so I'm changing those missing to other
#I think the otnly school without a region is Embry Riddle


MinSal<-min(total$Starting.Median.Salary) #Creating a minimum starting median salary
MaxSal<-max(total$Starting.Median.Salary) #Creating a maximum starting median salary

ui <- fluidPage(
  # setBackgroundColor(color = c("#66e0ff", "#00a3cc", "#003d4d")), #Don't have shinythemes, not necessary to your question
  titlePanel("Where does it pay to attend college?"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(tags$style(".well {background-color:#e6f9ff;}"),
                 sliderInput(inputId = "range",
                             label = "Choose the starting median salary range:", #Originally was Chose the year range:
                             min = MinSal, 
                             max = MaxSal,
                             value = c(MinSal*1.25, MaxSal*.75)), #Default value is .25% and .75% between min/max
                 selectInput(inputId = "dis",
                             label = "Chose the School type",
                             choices = unique(total$School.Type)),
                 checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "con",
                                    label = "Region of the school ",
                                    choices = unique(total$Region),
                                    selected = unique(total$Region)[1])
                 
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1")) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  df_dat<-reactiveValues("combined" = NULL) #Create a NULL reactiveValues. This is where we will store the data used for the graph
  
  observeEvent(c(input$con, input$dis, input$range),{ #Observes these inputs for changes
    #Also, observeEvent was previously assigned to a variable, which I don't think is needed so I removed that.
    req(input$con, input$dis, input$range)
    
    df_dat$combined<-total%>% #Using the total data from above, filter using the conditions you set up, and add it to the reactiveValue
      filter(between(Starting.Median.Salary, input$range[1], input$range[2]), 
             School.Type == input$dis,
             Region %in% input$con)
    
  })
  
  observe(print(str(df_dat$combined))) #Print the reactiveValue
  
  # create a graph 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

    req(df_dat$combined) #Requires the reactiveValue to make the graph

    # plot filtered data 
    #This was my understanding of what you wanted for a graph. It was pretty unclear in the question though, so this is just a guess. 
    ggplot(df_dat$combined) + aes(x = Starting.Median.Salary, y = School.Name, colour = Region, group = Region) +
      #added the group section so the line is based on each region.
      geom_line()+
      geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```